# How to add new line in modal body in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a modal for error messages.
I would like to make modal body messages multilined without changing the template of the modal, any help would be great..

```
<div class="modal-body" >
   <p *ngIf="!_isTranslatable">{{_modalBody}}</p>
</div>
```

I tried

```
this._modalBody = "Something went Bad<br>"+error ;
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` :

```
<div class="modal-body" >
   <p *ngIf="!_isTranslatable" [innerHTML]="_modalBody"></p>
</div>
```

Link to [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-u47y74?file=app/app.component.html).